# What do you call someone who is supported?

Tags: single-word-requests

Synonym for a supportee (Which doesn't seem to be a word)?

I created products that retail and we sell them and give the proceeds to charities. Trying to figure out a single word to use as a page title for those that we support were we can list the charities (With their permission of course).

Thanks

Comment: supportee/supporter cf. employee/employer, does beneficiaries fit the context?

Answer (score 14):

> **[Beneficiary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beneficiary)**
>
> *a person or thing that receives help or an advantage from something
>   :*
>
> *one that benefits from something*.

Answer (score 4):

**[Recipient](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recipient)** seems appropriate. Does this work for your project?

[image: recipient]

Note:'Supportee' *seems* singular and somewhat anonymous. "Suportees" sounds awkward and a bit silly to my ears. 'Beneficiaries' is indeed a proper word to describe these particular clients but it has a definite "business" connotation without much empathy. Given this is a charitable endeavor whose **recipients** are actual people who need assistance, a descriptor that has some dignity to it, in my opinion, has the most merit.

Comment: You should cite and link your source.  And since it’s textual information it ought to be text.  This looks like Google and I find that it’s hard to cite those definitions that pop up so I tend to pick  a different online dictionary.

Comment: @Jim So linked.

Answer (score 3):

*Supportee* is a word. The Ngram viewer finds it's used particularly for emotional support:

> Gottlieb explored several different support situations and assessed the degree to which various support behaviors are considered helpful to the **supportee**. (*[On Being Supportive: The Emotional Consequences of Listening to Another's Distress](https://books.google.com/books?id=0AARAQAAIAAJ&q=%22supportee%22&dq=%22supportee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSwt3agsvSAhWDyyYKHe3iBtc4ChDoAQgvMAU)* by R M Perrine)

and for physical support:

> Support-edges for support relationships in the Initial State are called disassembly-support-edges. They are shown as solid, u-shaped edges. These edges are directed from the **supportee** to the supporter. ([*Intelligent robotics: proceedings of the International Symposium on Intelligent Robotics, January 2-5, 1991*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qRVFAQAAIAAJ&q=%22supportee%22&dq=%22supportee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqo7KahcvSAhXJSCYKHQNdAAUQ6AEIJjAC))

and in the discussion of tax law:

In the case of a charitable trust...an alternative responsiveness test could be met when the **supportee** was named, and the named supportee had the power to enforce the trust.... ([*Tax Planning and Compliance for Tax-Exempt Organizations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_NE3DgAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22supportee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj99Pj-g8vSAhUHyyYKHaUdDjs4FBDoAQhCMAg#v=onepage&q=%22supportee%22&f=false) by J Blazek)

Checking with the google finds that *supportee* has been used for product support. From the [website](http://www.gosupportnow.com/web_conferencing/desktop_conferencing_support.html) of a desktop conferencing service:

> You can use GoMeetNow to remotely support PC and Mac computers. Follow
>   the procedure below:
>
> 1. Start an interactive meeting session & invite the **supportee**
>      (attendee) to join your session
> 2. After supportee joins your session, change the presenter to
>      **supportee**.
> 3. After **supportee** accepts to show his desktop, ask him to assign  controller to you.